# Adding a migrations gives filename already exists

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have enabled migrations as such:

```
enable-Migrations -ProjectName ProjectOne -ContextTypeName MyIdentity.Config.MyIdentityContext -MigrationsDirectory Identity\\Migrations
```

I specified my context as it is in a separated namespace, and i specified the directory because i want to have the migrations in a different directory.

After enabling the migrations like this, i get the expected configuration file in the expected location (Identity\Migrations folder) (i removed the comments in the seed procedure)

```
Friend NotInheritable Class Configuration
    Inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration(Of MyIdentityDbContext)

    Public Sub New()
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = False
        MigrationsDirectory = "Identity\\Migrations"
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context As MyIdentityDbContext)

    End Sub

End Class
```

After this I create a migration:

```
add-migration Initial
```

But then i get an error stating that the file already exists:

```
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040400): Unable to add '201506111233565_Initial.vb'. A file with that name already exists.

Server stack trace: 
at EnvDTE.ProjectItems.AddFromFileCopy(String FilePath)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at EnvDTE.ProjectItems.AddFromFileCopy(String FilePath)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.AddFile(Project project, String path)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.AddFile(Project project, String path, String contents)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationWriter.Write(ScaffoldedMigration scaffoldedMigration, Boolean rescaffolding, Boolean force, String name)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.WriteMigration(String name, Boolean force, ScaffoldedMigration scaffoldedMigration, Boolean rescaffolding)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Unable to add '201506111233565_Initial.vb'. A file with that name already exists.
```

When i look in the solution explorer (after refreshing) the file is there, but excluded from the project.

When I remove the MigrationsDirectory = "Identity\Migrations" it is working fine (but the migration file is being created in \Migrations)

I dont think it is relevant but to be sure: I'm also using Team explorer 2013 for source control on this project.

Comment: You should be able to delete the migration file and repeat. Try using a different name like Init2 and see if that works. You could check the source explorer to make sure nothing was checked in that is causing a conflict.

Comment: I tried with different names, deleting the file and made sure everything is checked in to the source control.

Comment: I have a feeling that he creates the file as an excluded file, and when he wants to do something else with it, he forgets it was excluded and tries to create it again. (but thats just a hunch)

Comment: Try using a single backslash here: -MigrationsDirectory Identity\Migrations instead of -MigrationsDirectory Identity\\Migrations

Comment: That's it! It's working properly now! Thanks!
If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your folder name is malformed so EF thinks it is a file. Try using a single backslash here: `-MigrationsDirectory Identity\Migrations` instead of `-MigrationsDirectory Identity\\Migrations`

Comment: This problem also happens when using a forward slash instead of a back slash.