# Enable-migration change location of migration folder

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project hierachy with two assemblies (for simplicity):

```
WebApi
 - Controllers
 - ...
DAL
 - Configurations
 - Context
```

Now I have this command enabling the migrations via the package manager console:

```
enable-migrations -ContextProjectName DAL -ContextTypeName Context
```

And it works fine but it inserts the **Migrations** folder into the WebApi project since that is the Startup project. How can I configure the command to select the DAL assembly as the place to store migrations, without changing the Startup project and using the package manager console?

I use **Entity Framework 6.1.3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the location of the EF Migrations "Migrations" folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546257/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-the-ef-migrations-migrations-folder)

Comment: That is not at all the same question. My question is within another assembly as well as via the package manager console. Anyways I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in how I actually managed to change the migrations folder via the package manager console, I added an extra line to the command:

```
enable-migrations -ContextProjectName DAL -ContextTypeName Context -ProjectName DAL
```

I found the solution by looking at the command references found [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/)